# reCAPTCHA container not found or already contains inner elements

Tags: javascript, android, html, database

Error in console web

> Error:reCAPTCHA container is either not found or already contains
>   inner elements!

I do not know how to solve this error. I want to do a web authentication by phone number from firebase

A quit the code but I do not know what goes in html

```
Window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier ('recaptcha-container');
```

What I have to do? Please help.

Comment: I guess the recaptcha container (element) either doesn't exist, or does exist but isn't empty - without more context it's hard to say which

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the id of the HTML tag meant for recaptcha matches the id used in the code above.
eg

```
div id="recaptcha-container">
```

for

```
Window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier ('recaptcha-container');
```

and one more thing, make sure that you use [the latest firebase sdk](https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.2/firebase.js)  link version to provide support for all firebase functions.